# Handling browser level authentication using Selenium in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I open the application,it prompts for a username and password. How can I handle this scenario using Selenium java in INTERNET EXPLORER?

Comment: What is special about Internet Explorer in this scenario ?  What about firefox say is that ok.  chrome and safari?

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/2755/8992

Comment: yeah i need to run the application in IE only, because application work much faster  in IE only

Comment: i'm automating the sanity check

Comment: Can you add the image of pop-up, since it may be a JS prompt or a modal window?

Comment: I realize this isn't SO, but showing what you've tried, what's working/not working, etc, are all still important for [asking a good question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) . . .

Comment: You cant use username:password@url in all browsers.. it works only in FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium doesn't offers much help in handling browser level authentications. You can use java robot class to handle browser level authentication as shown below:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public static void browserLevelAuthentication() throws AWTException{
   // initialize the web driver and open the web page
      WebDriver _webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
      webDriver.navigate().to("www.abc.com");


  // create robot for keyboard operations      
      Robot rb = new Robot();

  // Enter user name in username field 
 StringSelection username = new StringSelection("testUser1");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

  // press tab to move to password field
       rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
       rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
       Thread.sleep(2000);

  //Enter password in password field
       StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("testPassword");
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
       rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
       rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

  //press enter
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  }
```

Other than java robot class, you can also use Autoit tool to handle authentication.

Or you have to pass the username password in URL like

```
driver.get("http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<URL>")
```

Here `<USERNAME>` is username for that web application

, `<PASSWORD>` is password for above mentioned user

and `<URL>` is url of the web application

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. it works for me.. thanks a lot @ sarabjit

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how the browser level authentication box is coming up for starters. Is it a JS pop up or is it a modal window. Depending on this, you can use corresponding methods from Selenium - `driver.switch_to.alert` or `driver.switch_to.window()` methods- these are in python, but you have corresponding methods in Java also.

Also, you can refer to this [question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2755/handling-browser-level-authentication-using-selenium?lq=1), where it has been discussed in detail- though it is not IE specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Though you can use ROBOT class for this, but it highly recommended to avoid ROBOT class uses as much as you can.**

If I understood correctly, your website has authentication, it prompts the user name and password. you do not require to do anything with selenium.

You have to add username and password in url for example, your url is

```
driver.get("http://example.com")
```

you have to write it in this way

```
driver.get("http://username:password@example.com")
```

This will bypass the authentication window.

**INFO:** This kind of authentication to websites are done, to avoid google ranking, no one will like to rank their testing or dev sites in google